# Problem in using JQuery in IE6 for dynamic content selection

Tags: jquery, dynamic, internet-explorer-6

i am having problem to get value selected in select Element in which options are added dynamically using JQuery's html() in IE6 , but it works in IE8.

var column = $('#cmbSearch0')[0].value;

Answer (score 1):

Since id is unique you can do something like this.

Try

```
var column = $('#cmbSearch0').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

does the following work?

```
var column = $('#cmbSearch0').options[0].value;
```

Comment: rahul's is shorter and using jquery, use that :)